# App not launching on the simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am unable to install my app on the simulator. I always get the following error on the console,

> "Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error."

Please help !

Comment: Try restarting the Simulator as well as Xcode.

Comment: tried lot of times, but it isnt working out.Even i restarted the system as well

Comment: Have a look into these posts. [SO Post 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779115/iphone-failed-to-launch-simulated-application-unknown-error), [SO Post 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822972/xcode-error-failed-to-launch-simulated-application), [SO Post 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262898/failed-to-launch-simulated-application-unknown-error)

Comment: Please add comment for downvoting the answer

Answer (score 1):

Check info of your project whether Simulator is selected or Device. If it is Device change it to Simulator. Also check the base SDK version. 
I too had the same problem, fixed it with above checks. :)

Comment: thanks, i checked but it didnt helped me out.I created a new project & reused classes, then everything went fine.May be something went wrong with info.plist file