# Upgraded to xcode 4.5 and Mountain Lion and simulator stopped working

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ios6, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.5

I've scoured the questions asked here and thought I had found an answer earlier with deleting the data for the simulator, but my issue appears to be slightly different.

When I run the app, which was working on the last version of xcode and has been run on other systems in the simulator, in the simulator, it opens up the simulator and the simulator screen is black.  Not the normal black issue that I've seen where it is black but you can see the iPhone or iPad frame around the edge still, the whole simulator window is black like it hasn't loaded.

When I look in the debug log it always says this and only this "error: failed to attach to process ID 0".

I've tried the steps located [Xcode compiles my App, but can't run it in the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702201/xcode-compiles-my-app-but-cant-run-it-in-the-simulator) and I've uninstalled and re-installed xcode.  The issue still persists.

If anyone has any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you update to Xcode 4.5.1? I believe it was released yesterday and fixes some simulator related problems.

Comment: Yes, the re-install was done this morning.

Comment: Did you flush the DerivedData folder?

Comment: Yes, derived data folder was flushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the root doesn't run the simulator so we gave various folders and files permissions, sorry, long list and I was half working on it another person did the rest of the work, but if you run into this issue, start working in the non-root account (system admin also didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had this issue for a couple of days recently. I changed the device in the "Hardware" menu and it automagically started working.

Comment: We've tried it on a number of different device settings within the simulator and it is always a pure black screen.