# Xcode 4.6 builds, runs and finishes instantly (simulator iOS 6.1)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

In xcode, I tried to add a tap gesture to my app and when I built it, it started a problem with Xcode. It goes from building, 'running  on iPhone 6.1 simulator' to 'finished running on iPhone 6.1 simulator'.

If the simulator is closed, it starts up with a black screen and you cannot click the home button etc. If open, nothing happens, the app doesn't install but the simulator doesn't crash.

I have tried the armv6 architecture 'fix' but that didn't work. I have also cleaned the project and project data. I have reset the simulator multiple times as well.

If I add the old files to my new project, it works up to a point (I copy and paste old files into new) but then the same happens.

Thanks for your help in advance!

NOTE:
New blank projects build and run fine.

EDIT: It still didn't work after undoing my previous actions, and the simulator is responding according to Finder, although the screen stays black

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

UPDATE

I had a folder named 'resources' in my application, imported as a reference which, following links from the thread @arthan.v supplied me with fixed the problem. What I did was rename the folder to files and reimport it.

Thank you so much, I spent 2 days trying to fix it before now!

Comment: Does it say "Finished running ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}" XCode Status?

Comment: tried deleting derived data?

Comment: Reset content and settings of the simulator and then quit the simulator and xcode then reopen and run

Comment: @JamesWebster yes it does

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu Thats what i meant by project data

Comment: Ensure you haven't got your Info.plist included in your target's resourcse

Comment: @JamesWebster what do you mean?

Comment: I had this problem. Solved it with removing XCode and reinstalling it from scratch.

Comment: You are right about the folder named Resources. I got into this mess twice, both times when I added the folder to the bundle. Third time I renamed the folder to Res and it worked. Also I did the following to recover from the issue...
- Erased the derived data
- Reset the simulator
- Shut down the simulator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the `Center Button` in View on your right hand side of `Xcode`.
 [image]

In your Bottom bar, you'll see `error: failed to attach to process ID 0`.

Check these [error: failed to attach to process ID 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741188/error-failed-to-attach-to-process-id-0) and [Xcode compiles my App, but can't run it in the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702201/xcode-compiles-my-app-but-cant-run-it-in-the-simulator)

Comment: I can't say for certain that this is the cause of your problem, but it was when I had it.

Answer (score 2):

This sometimes gets fixed by these steps:

- iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings ... > Reset
- Xcode > Build and Run

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue after I had re-organized some code and renamed the workspace and project. Eventually realized there was an old version of my test app on the simulator's homescreen. I delete that and then everything was building fine again.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add the device to the provisioning profile. I experienced this on Xcode 6 and a real device.